# Init functions execution in multiple inheritance in python

Tags: python, oop

I am new to python and trying to understand the inheritance in python. Python has a feature of multiple inheritance. A single class can inherit more than one class at a same time. When we create an object of child class,the init function of child class is called. I want to call the init function of both the parent class of the child, but i am able to call only only one init function.I read the concept of method resolution order, by which the left most class inherited init function will be called. Please correct my code, so that the init function of both parent classes is called.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("in A Init")
    

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("in B Init")

    


class C(B,A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("in C Init")

cObj= C()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the `__init__` functions need to call `super().__init__()`, like this:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("in A Init")

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("in B Init")

class C(B, A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("in C Init")

c_obj= C()
```

When you invoke this you get the following output:

```
in A Init
in B Init
in C Init
```

Per the [`super()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), it returns a reference to "a parent or sibling" of the class, whichever is next in the method resolution order. At the top of the hierarchy, it returns a reference to the implicit parent class `object`, which has an empty `__init__` method which does nothing.

In order for this to work well, it's best for all the inherited `__init__` functions to have the same signature, including the common base class; in this case, the signature is just `__init__(self)` (no additional arguments), and the common base class is `object`, which also has `__init__(self)` with no additional arguments, so that's all good. Another common pattern is for them all to take keyword arguments and pass through `**kwargs` to the next one.

Comment: The solution works.The super().__init__()  function executes the init function of the parent class. But why we are putting the super().__init__() in the parent class ?

Comment: Explanation added to the answer; basically, the `super()` is not really "parent" but rather "next class in the inheritance graph"; in the simplest case that's the parent, but here it can also be sibling. At the top of the graph, it's the built-in `object`.